# What is the difference between Vてはじめる and はじめてV meaning?

Tags: grammar, aspect

例えば：
１．子供のとき、コーヒーをはじめて飲みました。
２．子供のとき、コーヒーを飲んではじめました。

I think both mean "When I was a child, I started/tried to drink coffee."

And how do I say "I drink coffee for the first time"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[初]{はじ}めてする means *I do for the first time*. しはじめる means *I start to do*.

しはじめる implies that you are doing that now.

So, sentence 1 is "I drank coffee for the first time" and 2 is "I started to drink coffee."

In addition, 飲んではじめました is unnatural. 飲みはじめました is natural.