# How to say "It was my first time canoeing"

Tags: translation

Is it "初めてのカヌー” or is that saying something like "It was my first canoe"?

Answer (score 2):

"初めてのカヌー体験です" is probably what I'd say to emphasize the experience of canoeing instead of the canoe itself. 経験 instead of 体験 would probably be alright as well.

Answer (score 1):

To express doing something for the first time, use the following conjunction:

> 〜初めて + action verb

Thus, for your desired sentence, `It was my first time canoeing.` would be expressed as

> カヌーを初めてしました。

References: [1](https://www.italki.com/question/226972), [2](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/35912/what-is-the-difference-between-v%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF%E3%81%98%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B-and-%E3%81%AF%E3%81%98%E3%82%81%E3%81%A6v-meaning)

Comment: In this specific context, I feel like カヌーをするのは初めてでした may be more appropriate, but I am not a native speaker.

Answer (score 0):

You can say 初めてのカヌーです for “This is my first time canoeing,” as well as, more colloquially, カヌー、初めてです。

This is an addition to the other answer.

Comment: Reading these sentences, I get the feeling that this is the first time seeing/owning a canoe (depends on context). By implication that means you haven't gone canoeing, but I'm not sure this has the right emphasis.